# OrderBy doesnt work on angular

Tags: angularjs

I'ama total noob on angular and I'am trying to order an array ,is not an object but the filter doesn't work

the view

```
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script data-semver="1.4.8" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular.js" data-require="angular.js@1.4.x"></script>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" data-semver="1.4.8" src="script.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="notas.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="miApp" ng-controller="CochesController  as c"> 
    <div ng-controller="PruebaController as pc">
      <table border="1">
        <tr ng-repeat="nota in pc.notas | orderBy: nota.nombre"  >
          <td>{{nota.nombre}}</td><td> {{nota.edad}}</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

the model

```
app.service('notasModel',function(){
    this.getNotas = function(){
        return [
            {
                id : 0,
                nombre : "Israel",
                edad : "32 años"
            },
            {
                id : 1,
                nombre : "Andrés",
                edad : "24 años"
            },
            {
                id : 2,
                nombre : "Juan",
                edad : "28 años"
            },
            {
                id : 3,
                nombre : "Pepito",
                edad : "18 años"
            },
            {
                id : 4,
                nombre : "Manuel",
                edad : "45 años"
            }
        ]
    }
})
```

and the controller

```
var app = angular.module('miApp', []);

app.controller('PruebaController',function($scope,notasModel){
   this.notas = notasModel.getNotas();
})
```

I've tried in many ways but the table isn't ordered,the order it's allways the same

Comment: Re-read the documentation and the examples. OrderBy takes the name of a property of the objects to order. You're passing the value of $scope.nota.nombre, which is undefined. What you want is `nota in pc.notas | orderBy:'nombre'`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<body ng-app="miApp" ng-controller="CochesController  as c"> 
<div ng-controller="PruebaController as pc">
  <table border="1">
    <tr ng-repeat="nota in pc.notas | orderBy: 'nombre'"  >
      <td>{{nota.nombre}}</td><td> {{nota.edad}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

The angular directive knows you're sorting `nota`

Comment: This way it works `<div ng-controller="PruebaController">
      <table border="1">
        <tr ng-repeat="nota in notas | orderBy: 'nombre'"  >
          <td>{{nota.nombre}}</td><td> {{nota.edad}}</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>`

Comment: I think that's what I put, I just included the whole app.

Comment: But with `ng-controller="PruebaController">`  instead of  `ng-controller="CochesController  as c"`

Comment: Yes that's just the difference between controller as and traditional controller usage. Controller as is actually preferred.

Answer (score 0):

Try the filter like this:

```
    <tr ng-repeat="nota in pc.notas | orderBy: 'nombre'"  >
      <td>{{nota.nombre}}</td><td> {{nota.edad}}</td>
    </tr>
```